# Accessing Value from JavaScript Callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to push the value from a Anglular.js service callback into an array. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
$scope.checkAddonDependencies = function(addon) {
    var addons = new Array();
    var arr = filterFilter($scope.addons, {checked: true});
    var length = arr.length, element = null;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        element = arr[i]['addoncode'];
        addons.push(element); //works fine

        myService.addon_dependencies(arr[i]['addoncode']).then(function(dependency) {
             addons.push(dependency); //not working
        });

    }

    console.log(addons);    
}
```

Comment: What does your service look like?

Comment: Weird...`addons` should be accessible inside that callback.

Comment: `addons.push(dependency);` should work. If not, you did something wrong somehow ;)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to handle the value in the callback like this:

```
myService.addon_dependencies(arr[i]['addoncode']).then(function(dependency) {
    addons.push(dependency); 
});
```

***Update***

Since the callback of the function `then()` is async, so there is no guarantee `console.log(addons)` shows anything in the code order.

Comment: @suncoastkid: You should remove `addons.push(dep);` of course.

Comment: We need to see how you implemented `addon_dependencies`

Comment: @suncoastkid values are pushed. the problem is the then() callback is async, so there is no guarantee console.log shows anything in the code order.